# Dispose after copying using CopyFile Method on vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, zip

I'm using the following code to copy a file in vb.net.

```
  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Originalloc, Stegresfolder, True)
```

But I can't access the file later in my code. It says Its already using by another program.How to dispose it after copying. Or any other solutions?

Comment: I don't think that `CopyFile` locks the destination file in any way. There must be another thing what is locking it

Comment: I think we need to see more code to determine if this is the problem or the if the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @pikoh and Bugs, Thanks for your advise I will review other parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a file lock too when using My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile.
Switching to File.copy solved this.